# Index & Matching to different sheet names in Excel in a list

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I have a list of sheet names of projects I am working on, I am trying to index match to the different sheet names to return a values from them.

For example in Cell a1 is ProjectA, a2 is Project B etc which has a corresponding sheet with that name. Is there any way to have index to a sheet that is in a list? I have tried doing a1 & "!C:C" but that creates an error.

Comment: Look into [`INDIRECT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out by @cybernetic.nomad, the `INDIRECT()` function will allow you to address cells by referring to them indirectly through text reference.

For example, when you have a sheet named 'Project A' and you want to to pull the value from cell A1 in that sheet, you can write the following in any other sheet of that workbook:

```
=INDIRECT("'Project A'!A1")
```